# Apache Spark : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, out-of-memory, java-heap

I am facing the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space` issue when I run the same spark program every 2nd time.

Here is a scenario:

When I do the `spark-submit` and runs the spark program for the first time, it gives me the correct output & everything is fine. When I execute the same `spark-submit` one more time, it is throwing `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space` exception.

***When it again works?***

If I run the same `spark-submit` after clearing the linux cache by executing - `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` it again runs successfully for one single time.

I tried setting all possible spark configs like memoryOverhead, drive-memory, executor-memory, etc.

Any idea whats happening here? Is this really a problem with spark code, or its happening because of some linux machine setting or the way cluster is configured?

Thanks.

Comment: it should mainly depend on JRE's version and implementation

Comment: I believe its do with underlying JVM settings. The resources should be cleaned up after spark job dies.

Comment: @QuickSilver - Thanks. Which JRE version / implementation we should go with? Can you please give some more clarity with some numbers? That will help a lot

Comment: @Constantine - Thanks for you reply. When we say JVM settings.. Where we should do the change & can you tell which exact property we need to configure in order to achieve this - `resources should be cleaned up after spark job dies`

Answer (score 0):

In case of using `df.persist()` or `df.cache()` then you should be also using `df.unpersist()` method and there's also `sqlContext.clearCache()` which clears all.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for the reply. We are not caching anything. But I will try `sqlContext.clearCache()` and update here